# How can a subclass of a subclass inherit methods from the first subclass' superclass?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlsIu.png)

I have posted the UML diagram for an assignment that asks to decode the color bands for a given resistor and return a string that returns the resistance in Ohms as well as its tolerance.

I am struggling a bit with the inheritance hierarchy and in the professor's problem description the LookupTable class is an abstract class with an abstract get() method. The NumberLookup and ToleranceLookup classes extend the LookupTable class and the MultiplierLookup class extends the NumberLookup class.

I guess what I am having the most trouble conceptualizing is whether or not the MultiplierLookup class is supposed to extend the LookupTable class or NumberLookup class.

**Here is the specific problem description:**

The ResistorDecoder object will be the object used by your Program.java to translate the array of colors into the human-friendly string. The ResistorDecoder will need several different types of lookup tables depending upon whether we are looking up a String from the colors or a numerical value. The LookupTable object is an abstract class since it contains an abstract method get(). The ToleranceLookup object takes a color and returns a String which is the tolerance string (e.g. ±5%). The NumberLookup object takes a color and can return a String but it also can return a Double. Since we are extending the LookupTable object (it didn't have the ability to return a double before) we need to inherit from the LookupTable object. The MultiplierLookup object works in a similar way to the NumberLookup object but the internal lookup tables are different. Therefore we need to inherit from the NumberLookup table even though we don't need to add any methods. Hint: Can you make the MultiplierLookup use the NumberLookup's getDouble behavior to simplify its responsibility?

Thus far, I have tried to create the various classes/subclasses as follows:

**LookupTable.java**

```
/**
 * abstract class with abstract method get()
 * 
 * 
 */

public abstract class LookupTable {

    /**
     * 
     * abstract class with abstract get method that has no implementation defined, behavior is defined in subclasses
     * 
     * @param color
     * @return 
     */
    abstract String get(String color);

}
```

**NumberLookup.java**

```
        public class NumberLookup extends LookupTable {
    private HashMap<String, String> numberTable = new HashMap<>();

    String get(String color) { // abstract method implementation
        return color;
    }

    public NumberLookup() {
        String[] colors = { "Silver", "Gold", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet",
                "Gray", "White" };
        for (String color : colors) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                numberTable.put(color, (i));
            }
        }

        // constructor

    }
/**
 * 
 * @param color
 * @return the corresponding 
 */

        public double getDouble(String color) { // new method

            return (numberTable.get(color));
    }

}
```

**ToleranceLookup.java**

```
/**
 * intakes a color and returns a String that is the tolerance String ex.( (+/-
 * 5%))
 * 
 * adds the OHM symbol and tolerance to the end of the final string to be
 * printer
 */

public class ToleranceLookup extends LookupTable {

    /**
     * 
     * default empty constructor
     */
    public ToleranceLookup() {

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param color band as a string
     * @return the Ohm and tolerance suffix
     */
    public String get(String color) {
        switch (color) {
        case "Black":
            return "\u03A9";
        case "Brown":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "1%");
        case "Red":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "2%");
        case "Orange":
            return ("\u03A9");
        case "Yellow":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "5%");
        case "Green":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + ".5%");
        case "Blue":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + ".25%");
        case "Violet":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + ".1%");
        case "Gray":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "10%");
        case "White":
            return ("\u03A9");
        case "Gold":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "5%");
        case "Silver":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "10%");
        case "None":
            return ("\u03A9, \u00B1" + "20%");
        default:
            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

**MultiplierLookup.java**

```
/**
 * inherits from the NumberLookup object but no methods need to be added.
 * 
 * Internal lookup table is different
 * 
 * 
 */

public class MultiplierLookup extends NumberLookup {
    private HashMap<String, Double> multiplier = new HashMap<>();

    String get(String color) {
        return color;
    }

    public MultiplierLookup() {// constructor
        String[] colors = new String[] { "Silver", "Gold", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue",
                "Violet", "Gray", "White" };
        for (String color : colors) {
            int j = -2;
            while (j <= 9) {
                multiplier.put(color, (Double.toString(Math.pow(10, j)));
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    public Double getDouble(String color) { // returns a double value
        return multiplier.get(color);

    }

}
```

I understand there are some errors in the code thus far, and I think I understand for the most part how to resolve them, but I am really new to OOP and interrelated/dependent classes. Although I understand how inheritance works on a basic level, I am unsure how to get my MultiplierLookup class to inherit from both NumberLookup and LookupTable. Sorry if this question is verbose and or too basic, but I have spent a good amount of time browsing through this site for all of my assignments and the input on here is literally invaluable, so I thought this would be the best place to turn to.

I do not by any means expect anyone to complete this code for me and I actually really enjoy the problem solving, but I feel that having the concepts explained to me with a concrete example to work with will be beneficial. Thank you in advance!

Also, I've not quite constructed the ResistorDecoder class yet because of its reliance on the subclasses. But it is mostly going to compose a string based off of information from the other classes.

Comment: The resistor colours might be better as a Java Enum.

Comment: I had considered using enum, but I wasn't sure how to account for lowercase characters for the array of strings in the ResistorDecoder object, since I was under the impression that Enum declarations required all caps. Is this incorrect?

Comment: `The NumberLookup and ToleranceLookup classes extend the LookupTable class and the MultiplierLookup class extends the NumberLookup class` 
Is this a specification of your prof?

Comment: Yes it is, the exercise is to utilize inheritance and abstract classes, so the problem description is verbatim what was issued by my professor.